# FFmpeg avcodec_decode_video2 decode RTSP H264 HD-video packet to video picture with error

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I used `FFmpeg` library `version 4.0` to have simple C++ program, in witch is a thread to receive `RTSP H264` video data from IP-camera and display it in program window.

Code of this thread is follow:

```
DWORD WINAPI GrabbProcess(LPVOID lpParam)
// Grabbing thread
{
  DWORD i;
  int ret = 0, nPacket=0;
  FILE *pktFile;
  // Open video file
  pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
  if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, nameVideoStream, NULL, NULL)!=0)
      fGrabb=-1; // Couldn't open file
  else
  // Retrieve stream information
  if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0)
      fGrabb=-2; // Couldn't find stream information
  else
  {
      // Find the first video stream
      videoStream=-1;
      for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
        if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
          videoStream=i;
          break;
        }
      if(videoStream==-1)
          fGrabb=-3; // Didn't find a video stream
      else
      {
          // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
          pCodecCtxOrig=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
          // Find the decoder for the video stream
          pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtxOrig->codec_id);
          if(pCodec==NULL)
              fGrabb=-4; // Codec not found
          else
          {
              // Copy context
              pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
              if(avcodec_copy_context(pCodecCtx, pCodecCtxOrig) != 0)
                  fGrabb=-5; // Error copying codec context
              else
              {
                  // Open codec
                  if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL)<0)
                      fGrabb=-6; // Could not open codec
                  else
                  // Allocate video frame for input
                  pFrame=av_frame_alloc();
                  // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
                  numBytes=avpicture_get_size(pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width,
                      pCodecCtx->height);
                  buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));
                  // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrame
                  // Note that pFrame is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
                  // of AVPicture
                  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrame, buffer, pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                      pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

                  // Allocate video frame for display
                  pFrameRGB=av_frame_alloc();
                  // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
                  numBytes=avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width,
                      pCodecCtx->height);
                  bufferRGB=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));
                  // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameRGB
                  // Note that pFrameRGB is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
                  // of AVPicture
                  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, bufferRGB, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                      pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
                  // initialize SWS context for software scaling to FMT_RGB24
                  sws_ctx_to_RGB = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width,
                      pCodecCtx->height,
                      pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                      pCodecCtx->width,
                      pCodecCtx->height,
                      AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                      SWS_BILINEAR,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      NULL);

                  // Allocate video frame (grayscale YUV420P) for processing
                  pFrameYUV=av_frame_alloc();
                  // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
                  numBytes=avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pCodecCtx->width,
                      pCodecCtx->height);
                  bufferYUV=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));
                  // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameYUV
                  // Note that pFrameYUV is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
                  // of AVPicture
                  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameYUV, bufferYUV, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                      pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
                  // initialize SWS context for software scaling to FMT_YUV420P
                  sws_ctx_to_YUV = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width,
                      pCodecCtx->height,
                      pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                      pCodecCtx->width,
                      pCodecCtx->height,
                      AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                      SWS_BILINEAR,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      NULL);
                RealBsqHdr.biWidth = pCodecCtx->width;
                RealBsqHdr.biHeight = -pCodecCtx->height;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  while ((fGrabb==1)||(fGrabb==100))
  {
      // Grabb a frame
      if (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
      {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream)
        {
            // Decode video frame
            int len = avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
            nPacket++;
            // Did we get a video frame?
            if(frameFinished)
            {
                // Convert the image from its native format to YUV
                sws_scale(sws_ctx_to_YUV, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
                    pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height,
                    pFrameYUV->data, pFrameYUV->linesize);
                // Convert the image from its native format to RGB
                sws_scale(sws_ctx_to_RGB, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
                    pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height,
                    pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
                HDC hdc=GetDC(hWndM);
                SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height,
                    0, 0, 0, pCodecCtx->height,pFrameRGB->data[0], (LPBITMAPINFO)&RealBsqHdr, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
                ReleaseDC(hWndM,hdc);
                av_frame_unref(pFrame);
            }
        }
        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
      }
   }
   // Free the org frame
  av_frame_free(&pFrame);
  // Free the RGB frame
  av_frame_free(&pFrameRGB);
  // Free the YUV frame
  av_frame_free(&pFrameYUV);

  // Close the codec
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
  avcodec_close(pCodecCtxOrig);

  // Close the video file
  avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
  avformat_free_context(pFormatCtx);

  if (fGrabb==1)
      sprintf(tmpstr,"Grabbing Completed %d frames", nCntTotal);
  else if (fGrabb==2)
      sprintf(tmpstr,"User break on %d frames", nCntTotal);
  else if (fGrabb==3)
      sprintf(tmpstr,"Can't Grabb at frame %d", nCntTotal);
  else if (fGrabb==-1)
      sprintf(tmpstr,"Couldn't open file");
  else if (fGrabb==-2)
      sprintf(tmpstr,"Couldn't find stream information");
  else if (fGrabb==-3)
      sprintf(tmpstr,"Didn't find a video stream");
  else if (fGrabb==-4)
      sprintf(tmpstr,"Codec not found");
  else if (fGrabb==-5)
      sprintf(tmpstr,"Error copying codec context");
  else if (fGrabb==-6)
      sprintf(tmpstr,"Could not open codec");
  i=(UINT) fGrabb;
  fGrabb=0;
  SetWindowText(hWndM,tmpstr);
  ExitThread(i);
  return 0;
}
// End Grabbing thread
```

When program receive `RTSP H264` video data with resolution `704x576` then decoded video pictures are OK. When receive `RTSP H264` HD-video data with resolution `1280x720` it look like that first video picture is decoded OK and then video pictures are decoded but always with some error.

Please help me to fix this problem!

Here is problems brief :
I have an IP camera model `HI3518E_50H10L_S39` (product of China).
Camera can provide H264 video stream both at resolution 704x576 (with RTSP URI "rtsp://192.168.1.18:554/user=admin_password=tlJwpbo6_channel=1_stream=1.sdp?real_stream") or 1280x720 (with RTSP URI "rtsp://192.168.1.18:554/user=admin_password=tlJwpbo6_channel=1_stream=0.sdp?real_stream").
Using `FFplay` utility I can access and display them with good picture quality.
For testing of grabbing from this camera, I have a simple (above mentioned) program in VC-2005. In "Grabbing thread" program use `FFmpeg` library version 4.0 for opening camera RTSP stream, retrieve stream information, find the first video stream... and prepare some variables.
Center of this thread is loop: Grab a frame (function `av_read_frame`) - Decode it if it's video (function `avcodec_decode_video2`) - Convert to RGB format (function `sws_scale`) - Display to program window (GDI function `SetDIBitsToDevice`).
When proram run with camera RTSP stream at resolution 704x576, I have good video picture. Here is a sample:
[704x576 sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU9Rw.jpg)
When program run with camera RTSP stream at resolution 1280x720, first video picture is good:
[First good at res.1280x720](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfeYE.jpg)
but then not good:
[not good at res.1280x720](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiAZc.jpg)
Its seem to be my FFmpeg function call to `avcodec_decode_video2` can't fully decode certain packet for some reasons.

Comment: Hi Nguyen, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  What is the actual error?  And could you simplify this to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Max, sorry for my limited English. I try to explain error in re-edited question. Hope in Your help